# read raw byte data from image

Tags: c#

I need to get raw data from Image and I am using Bitmap LockBits

the image is 24BppRgb but after creating the Bitmap, the bitmap format is 32BppArgb

Any idea why this happens

```
    System.Drawing.Bitmap bmp = new Bitmap(image);
    Rectangle rect = new Rectangle(0, 0, bmp.Width, bmp.Height);
    System.Drawing.Imaging.BitmapData bmpData = bmp.LockBits(rect, System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageLockMode.ReadOnly, image.PixelFormat);
    IntPtr ptr = bmpData.Scan0;
    int bytes = Math.Abs(bmpData.Stride) * bmp.Height;
    byte[] rgbValues = new byte[bytes];
    Marshal.Copy(ptr, rgbValues, 0, bytes);
    bmp.UnlockBits(bmpData);
    bmp.Dispose();
```

Comment: Are you specifying the color depth as 24BppRgb?

Comment: No the Image.pixelformat of the source jpg image is 24BppRgb

Comment: could you provide the related code?

Comment: question edited with code

Answer (score 0):

I suspect your original image is actually 32bppArgb. If this is the case, why not convert to RGB?

```
var bmp24bppRgb = new Bitmap(image.Width, image.Height, PixelFormat.Format24bppRgb);

using (var g = Graphics.FromImage(bmp24bppRgb))
{
  g.DrawImage(image, new Rectangle(0, 0, image.Width, image.Height));
}
```

... and then use your code to access the bits of the converted image.